# Uniswap V3's Position NFTS "positions()" returning irregular results for tokensOwed

Tags: web3.py, uniswap, fees, staking

I'm messing around with web3py and I ran into something that I haven't been able to understand; when I call positions() on a tokenid, I get odd results for the tokensOwed values. The results don't match what I see on the app.uniswap.org/#/pool/{TOKEN_ID} url; some times there are values that are just off from what's listed, other times it just straight up returns a 0.

This isn't unique to web3py, if I call the function from the contract's etherscan page, I also get an incorrect return value. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: It would help with some code.

Comment: It's not really a matter of code, I'm calling the positions function located here: https://etherscan.io/token/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88#readContract

Comment: It does. We cannot determine what goes wrong (if there is) if we do not know what the functions do.